# Request for Shopify API to allow creation of Customers and Orders

Tags: api, shopify

I would just like to check if there is any update on when the Shopify API will have the ability to create orders? Currently we can only retrieve, edit and delete orders.

Is this on the roadmap (and if so, can you give me a rough ETA) or will it never be exposed?

Thanks,

Stuart.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a feature request for another site.

Answer (score 3):

This is something we are considering, there is no ETA.

Comment: I would love to have the ability to create orders